# Why bundle version a control plugin with an IDE?

Tags: version-control, ide

I was always wondering why it is a big deal having version control support inside an IDE.

I always preferred to use a command-line/standalone version of the version control of choice and never found IDE integration helpful.

I know it can be helpful sometimes, for example to automatically keep track of renames, but I was bitten by version control plugins a couple of times (especially the [ClearCase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_ClearCase) [Eclipse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29) plugin) that I'm now finding it counter productive compared to the command-line version, where I have better control.

What is your opinion?

Comment: I've had horrible horrible experience (and still do) with the Subclipse plugin for Eclipse. Made me swear to use CVS until Eclipse natively includes SVN support (which it really really really should by now).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Integration of the IDE with version control and, in particular, [software change management](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_control) (SCM) helps bringing together the philosophies of the IDE and the source control system.

One example is temporary files and binaries, that should not be checked-in and, e.g. in Visual Studio, end up within the source directory if you're not carefully creating new project and solution templates with a non-default directory configuration.

Another could be tracking of work items and complex bug fixes.

Also it saves some ceremony and context-switching when editing files.

Advanced integrations may also allow to push the change management system's concept of "configuration" ("branch", "tag", "view") into the IDE.

ClearCase integration, however, is clearly not "advanced".

Answer (score 5):

Integrated Source Control also helps to only keep the important files under Source control. For example, when I add a new File in Visual Studio, the Plugin (visualSVN) will allow me to add it easily without me having to remember to go outside of my IDE and run the command to add it to the repository. On the other hand, it will automatically ignore temporary files, like the obj/ and bin/ Folders.

Essentially: Integrated Version Control that actually works is a great way to keep the repository clean and complete.

Answer (score 4):

I like how **some** IDE's implement this. [Ankh-SVN](http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/) for Visual Studio is not that great and is a bit buggy, however [Subeclipse](http://subclipse.tigris.org/) I find to work exceedingly well when I'm using Eclipse.

I think it really depends on the IDE you're using and the quality of that plug-in. It's going to work well for some setups and terrible for others.

That's why I like Subversion with Tortoise SVN so much. I can choose to use the IDE integration when and where it makes sense, otherwise, just like you said, I can simply use the command line or in my case, the windows explorer based client!

Answer (score 2):

A lot of it is simply the preference and comfort level of the user.  Some folks are comfortable with the command line.  Some prefer a GUI.

I wouldn't make generalized assumptions that all version control within the IDE is bad or buggy based on experiences with a particular plugin which had issues.

Answer (score 2):

Why even have an IDE?  Why not just do everything with a command line? ;)

The answer is that having it integrated with the IDE is "better".

My #1 reason:
You can visually see if a file is checked out or not, and if you need to edit a file, you can take the action right there where you are working.

There are more, but that is the big one.

Answer (score 1):

It's depend on your IDE and the way you work with VCS.

Me and my team using VSS plugin-ins inside Delphi IDE, it gives a lot of flexibable feature when working together for example, All our forms are check-in when you start to write a letter or move components it asked if you want to check-out the code file or form.

also when some one change any code in other forms, it pop up and telling you it's already update by someone else and asking you to update current files in your H.D.

and you just get everything while you are in the IDE, you don't need to move to other external file, or command prompt to do a simple task.

I find most people who like to deal with command prompt working mostly in code without GUI IDE or may I be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Nearly all of my subversion needs can be handled by the IDE interface.  It's a lot faster to do 2 quick clicks than pop up a command line, cd to the right place, issue the command, etc.

Command line has it's place, but with the current crop of IDEs, that place continues to shrink.

Answer (score 1):

I have battle scars from using a buggy implementation of an IDE/VCS integration.  In all honesty, if it was not buggy it would have been great.  As long as there are great tools like TortoiseSVN, I don't see a need for IDE/VCS integration.  I'd rather have more tools that do their job well than a few buggy tools.

Answer (score 0):

Version control support in an IDE generally gives you a better view. The IDE actually knows what type of file you are looking at when doing a diff, which means it can do context highlighting and help you do merges more effectively.

I also think it saves setup time. In stead of installing all kinds of tools, a developer can download the IDE, do a checkout an be on it's way. If every developer on a project uses the same IDE, they can help eachother.

"Counterproductive" is a large word. If you have serious CVS/SVN problems maybe once a month, it's still way to few to have complicated clients installed on all your dev machines.

Answer (score 0):

I have both systems where there is an integrated IDE (Microsoft FrontPage against an IIS Development Web site with Visual Source Safe on all of the web content) and where there is not (java command-line development, Visual Studio Express Editions).  An intermediate case that I use is jEdit 4.x with VSS integration via plug-in.

I think the integrated case is valuable for the reason it always is -- you don't have to leave your application to interact with source-control functions and you don't have to worry about remembering to add new files and to check out files before editing them.  The ability to have a smooth work process and to minimize the risk of oversights is powerful, as far as I am concerned.  Even when the IDE-plugin integration is less than perfect (the jEdit 4.x case), I still prefer it over not having it.

I also agree that having explorer integration on Windows, the case for Tortoise SVN, is also a great capability, even when IDE integration is available.  This allows convenient operation without having to launch the IDE while also being able to launch from the explorer window into the IDE (depending on file type) or editor or make or whatever while operating in Windows Explorer.

And yes, the command-line interfaces remain valuable, especially for scripting of recuring-operation patterns.

I operate in many contexts.  Having low barriers and fluidity of operation in all of them is to be prized.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the question. IDEs by definition are integrated, meaning that they're supposed to help you avoid the need to get out of the environment for anything project-related. Version control obviously fits the bill.

If you're looking for more practical reasons, one is that IDEs can offer you awareness by the nature of their graphical presentation. Eclipse, for example, will present files and directories that have changed. With additional plugins or suites, you can ever get real-time awareness as soon as another user is editing the same file, helping you predict a merge conflict before it occurs. I'm not familiar with a commandline based mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

I use intellij integrated with cvs on a regular basis and by far the best feature of the integration of version control inside the IDE is line-by-line indications of what is added, edited, or deleted along with easy access (mouse hover/tool tip) to the pre-edit changes.

This is all within the source code in a non-obtrusive way.

For the nuts and bolts of version control (checkin/checkout/update/etc) I sometimes use the IDE and sometimes use the command line.

Answer (score 0):

The number 1 reason for an SCM integrated with the IDE is that it makes it more effortless to use it and eliminates the need to REMEMBER to check things out. Through experience I have seen that steps that developers construe as extraneous, which often encompases anything other than writing code, don't get done. Making them do extra steps increases the odds that developers won't bother with it and will work around the source control system